# Php confirm box

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a text box in that if user enters a value it will go to db and check that value =y if so it has give an alert to user like would you like to activa if ok it should rediredc  to other page if no also redirect to some page.
Alert box should have yes or no

I don't know whether my sql script is wrong or the java script

```
$activate = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `thirdpartycategorymaster` WHERE `delete` =  'y' ");
$activate='y';
if($activate)
{
header("location:catact.php");
}
else
{
$activate='NULL';
header("location:tp_home.php");
}



$checkformembers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM thirdpartycategorymaster WHERE ThirdPartyCategoryName = '$ThirdPartyCategoryName'");

$no=0;

if ($ThirdPartyCategoryName)
{
 if(mysql_num_rows($checkformembers) != 0)
 {
 header('location:newcat.php?msg=category exists');
 }
 else
 {
 $sql="INSERT INTO  thirdpartycategorymaster (ThirdPartyCategoryID, ThirdPartyCategoryName)
 VALUES
 ('$_POST[ThirdPartyCategoryID]',
 '$_POST[ThirdPartyCategoryName]'
 )";
 $no=1;
 header('location:tp_home.php?add=Category Added Successfully');
 }

 if (!mysql_query($sql,$conn))
 {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }
}
else
header('location:tp_home.php');

/*if ($no==1)
header("Location:tp_home.php?msg=Category Added Successfully");
else
header("Location:tp_home.php");
*/
mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: which javascript? Don't see anything.

Comment: I also don't see any javascript. The only thing I see is very unsafe code(MySQL) => Use PDO!

Comment: I hope you're sanitizing those values before building query strings with them, otherwise google for "bobby tables"

Answer (score 0):

Do you considered using a framework like [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/)?

You can not display a alert dialog with php! You need javascript to realize that. E.g.:

```
<a href="#" 
  onclick="if confirm('Sure?') { window.location='http://mysite.de/xy/delete';}">
    Click to delete
</a>
```

Working example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/BBuwL/

But consider what happens if the user has javascript disabled, or if google comes along and spiders the link.

A better way would be to post a form to confirm. So in php you could redirect to a confirmation page with a form that holds a yes and a no button.